# Deleted /usr/include by mistake

Tags: delete

Like a real idiot, I deleted my

> /usr/include

on 13.04, is there anyway I can retrieve this?

Comment: so do i :( trying to install compile ncl, because ncl-ncarg had dependency problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/usr/include contains data about your packages, which means that a fresh install wouldn't write anything to it. I'm afraid your system has suffered a great loss.

Maybe you could try an update for your packages, but from experience, I know this doesn't usually work with Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If your lucky, the apt cache will still have information about packages that used /usr/include. You can find a list using `dpkg -S /usr/include/*`, and use `sudo apt-get reinstall [package]` to fix things.

**Edit** : Best solution found in the comments :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/include/*|cut -d':' -f1|tr -d ','|tr '\n' ' ')
```

In order to reinstall all packages that where corrupted.

Comment: Hi thanks I ran dpkg -S /usr/include/* and got a massive list, how do I use this information with sudo apt-get reinstall [package] ?

Comment: The list you got is the list of packages that used things in /usr/include. By reinstalling it, you'll repopulate them. Think about recreating /usr/include if you deleted the directory (as root). You could do something like `sudo apt-get reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/include/*|cut -d':' -f1|tr -d ','|tr '\n' ' ')` but keep in mind that it is **RISKY**.

Comment: thanks it says, apt-get reinstall is an invalid operation

Comment: My bad. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/include/*|cut -d':' -f1|tr -d ','|tr '\n' ' ')` - Still as **RISKY**

Comment: Perhaps I should do a back up first?

Comment: Could be a great idea. Especially if it fails, and you have to reinstall a fresh install (last resort) to avoid package corruption :) I don't think you'd loose anything from /home, but who knows...

Comment: It looks like everything is fixed, I got only one line saying update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/openmpi/include because link group mpi is broken

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I am going to mark this as solved, one more thing, where did you learn such awesome ninja regexes like that? :)

Comment: You have to go by steps, it's not regex. It take the content of dpkg (`dpkg ...`), cuts it following the ':' to get packages names only, then I remove ',' which are disturbing, and I finally change end of lines into spaces. In the end, I got a list of packages, and names a just separated with spaces. Check the final output using `dpkg -S /usr/include/*|cut -d':' -f1|tr -d ','|tr '\n' ' '`. Just have to place it in the apt-get command, and everything goes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi (and thanks for solution), some additional commands used by me:

```
dpkg -S /usr/include/*|cut -d':' -f1|tr -d ','|tr '\n' ' ' > app.list
cat app.list | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq > sortapp.list
cat sortapp.list | tr '\n' ' ' > sortapp-2.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $( cat sortapp-2.list )
```